# NAudio piping WaveIn or WaveProvider to Stream

Tags: c#, naudio

I'd like to use WaveIn / WaveProvider / WavOut feature from NAudio to manipulate the Microhpone (or other source)

```
WaveIn recorder = new WaveIn();
recorder.DataAvailable += RecorderOnDataAvailable;
BufferedWaveProvider buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(recorder.WaveFormat);
```

But at the end I need to convert the buffer to stream because SpeechRecognitionEngine works with Stream.

```
engine.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, format);
```

How can I pipe a WavProvider to a Stream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figure out a working solution:

1) Build a WaveIn

```
  waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
  waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
  waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 2);
  waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
```

2) Build a PipeStream

```
  buffer = new PipeStream();
  engine.SetInputToAudioStream(buffer, waveIn.WaveFormat);
```

3) Copy WaveIn to Buffer

```
void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) {
  buffer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

It works fine and there is no need to worry about. Buffer size already handle by PipeStream.